# iPhone YouTube embed with iframe

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, mobile-safari, youtube-api

Any idea why no matter what height i assign to the iframe, it doesn't resize? I'm testing this on an iPhone (on desktop browser it resizes correctly).

```
<iframe width="320" height="180" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/wwbKu0mznf4" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try adding scrolling="no".

```
<iframe scrolling="no" src="..." width="320" height="180"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

iPhone doesn't support iframe height attribute. Try putting the iFrame in a div like this:

```
.scroll {
  height:200px;
  width:200px;
  overflow:auto;
}


<div class="scroll">content</div>
```

Comment: I've seen this solution before, but it will hide the video snapshot that appears at first. I will not be able to see the PLAY button either.

Comment: @niovhe: try using javascript to resize the iframe. See if that does the trick.

Comment: <iframe id="YTvideo" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/wwbKu0mznf4"></iframe>
    <script>document.getElementById('YTvideo').style.height = 180;</script>

No luck, but thanks for the idea :)

Comment: No no, if you look closely after the code, i had my comment :)

Answer (score 0):

When you rewrite the height with javascript use a %.  Not sure why but it seems to be the only thing that works.  A good number to start with is height="20%"

Here is what I've been using.

```
/* patch Ipad Youtube */ 
var agent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase(); 
var patchApple = (agent.indexOf('iphone')!=-1) || (agent.indexOf('ipad')!=-1);

if (patchApple) { $('iframe').css({ 'height':'20%' }); }
```